# Which preposition should be used with contrario and why?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, idiom, grammar-choice, meaning

Is it better to say *argumentum a/ab contrario* or *e/ex contrario*?

It seems that both are acceptable but in most Romance languages it is *a contrario*.

The movement out/from is not clear/explicit/graphic and it is a concept/mental abstraction that "moves", not a physical object.

EDIT secondary questions following up to clarify as suggested
**Why ex and not ab? Why do most Romance Languages have a contrario instead? How did ex contrario evolve to a contrario?**

Answer (score 4):

This is just a follow-up post to Sebastian's answer, which is correct for Classical Latin. It could be useful to add that the expression *a contrario* (often used as part of *argumentum a contrario*) comes from **scholastic Latin**. The expression *a contrario* is typically used in Romance-speaking countries, in English-speaking countries, in Slavic-speaking countries, etc. In contrast, the classical form is more typically found in German-speaking countries, in Scandinavian countries, etc.
As for OP's question ("How did *ex contrario* evolve to *a contrario*?"), I think it is not a matter of "evolution" (?) but rather of "replacement" of *e(x)* 'out of, from' by *a(b)* 'from' in this [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_e_contrario). As for the question why such a substitution did not (typically) take place in, let's say, Sebastian's or Joonas's countries (Germany and Finland, respectively; cf. supra), I don't know.

Comment: Actually, I would say my answer was just plain wrong, because I had simply overlooked the word *argumentum* in the question. I have deleted it.

Comment: Just so this answer does not look completely out of context to readers who cannot see my deleted answer (that takes a certain reputation, I believe), I wrote that only *ex contrario* is correct. That is the case for the classical expression *e/ex contrario* which means "on the contrary." But an *argumentum e/a contrario* is something completely different.